How to host a publicly available MongoDB server locally?
I am using MongoDB community server to host a server locally on a Windows computer . I wish to connect remotely from a Linux server over pymongo, but I get TimeoutException as the Python instance cannot establish a connection to my MongoDB server. However, I am able to connect to the server from the same network, just not outside my WiFi.
Local environment:
OS: Windows 11
db version: v7.0.8
distarch: x86_64
target_arch: x86_64
Remote environment:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
pymongo version: 4.6.2
Python version: 3.8
Is there something I am missing? Are you not supposed to be able to host locally on community server?
The instance is started on the command line using the script “mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0” with default port 27017. Confirmed that it is listening on 0.0.0.0:27017.
The router has been configured with portforwarding, routing external connections to the computer’s public IP on external port 27017 to the computer’s local IPv4 address on internal port 27017. My router is using DHCP but the local address is preferred and seems to remain quite static.
The Windows firewall has been configured to allow all connections on port 27017. I have even tried disabling the firewall to no avail.

Usually the WiFi router also has a firewall. Have a look at their settings. And please don't disable your firewall, you will regret it.

Did you run rs.initiate?  If there is a replica set configuration, the hostname used will need to be resolvable even if you use an IP in the connection string.

@WernfriedDomscheit I have configured my router's firewall to accept connections from the remote VM, but the problem persists. I am not sure what kind of network protocol pymongo is using, but I am assuming its built on top of TCP so that is what I am allowing.

@Joe I am not using a replica set.
